# + 1 к счёту за секунду по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame, таймер

Пишу простейший кликер на *pygame*.

Как по нажатию на кнопку (купить) каждую секунду мне прибавлялось очко к счёту?

Проблема, даже не затрагивает код, меня интересует сама логика как сделать так, чтобы каждую секунду прибавлять очки к счёту. 
Я пробовал через цикл `while`, но при этом всегда встречаю краш программы из-за бесконечного цикла. 
Я облазил все форумы и такое ощущение, что никто таким не занимался.

Код у меня на двух файлах Const(константы) и Main (основа).

```
import pygame as pg
from CONST import *
import time

def draw_obj():
global model_c
global b1
global b2
global b3
global b4

model_c = pg.Rect(circle_pos[0], circle_pos[1], 450, 450)
b1 = pg.Rect(button_pos[0], button_pos[1], 380, 100)
b2 = pg.Rect(button_pos[0], button_pos[1] + 130, 380, 100)
b3 = pg.Rect(button_pos[0], button_pos[1] + 260, 380, 100)
b4 = pg.Rect(button_pos[0], button_pos[1] + 390, 380, 100)
b5 = pg.Rect(button_pos[0], button_pos[1] + 520, 380, 100)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "white", model_c, border_radius=300)

pg.draw.rect(screen, 'white', rect)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "black", b1)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "black", b2)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "black", b3)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "black", b4)

pg.draw.rect(screen, "black", b5)


def Texts():
global score_t
global purchase_b1
global purchase_b2
global purchase_b3
global purchase_b4
global purchase_b5

score_text = f.render(f'Очки: {str(score)}',1,'white',None)
pos = circle_pos[0] + 145 , circle_pos[1] - 100
screen.blit(score_text,pos)

b1_text = f.render(f'Стоимость: {str(count_b1)}', 1, 'yellow', None)
pos_f_b1 = button_pos[0] + 20, button_pos[1] + 15
screen.blit(b1_text, pos_f_b1)

b2_text = f.render(f'Стоимость: {str(count_b2)}', 1, 'yellow', None)
pos_f_b2 = button_pos[0] + 20 , button_pos[1] + 15 + 130
screen.blit(b2_text, pos_f_b2)

b3_text = f.render(f'Стоимость: {str(count_b3)}', 1, 'yellow', None)
pos_f_b3 = button_pos[0] + 20 , button_pos[1] + 15 + 260
screen.blit(b3_text, pos_f_b3)

b4_text = f.render(f'Стоимость: {str(count_b4)}', 1, 'yellow', None)
pos_f_b4 = button_pos[0] + 20 , button_pos[1] + 15 +  390
screen.blit(b4_text, pos_f_b4)

b5_text = f.render(f'Стоимость: {str(count_b5)}', 1, 'yellow', None)
pos_f_b5 = button_pos[0] + 20 , button_pos[1] + 15 + 520
screen.blit(b5_text, pos_f_b5)

pg.init() #Инициализация
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:  #Логика игры
clock.tick(60)
if powerup == 11:
    powerup = 10

for event in pg.event.get():
    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
        is_running = False
    elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        if model_c.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            score = score + powerup
            print(score)
        elif b1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            if score >= count_b1:
                powerup += 10
                score = score - count_b1
                count_b1 += 100
        elif b1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            if score >= count_b1:
                powerup += 10
                score = score - count_b1
                count_b1 += 100
        elif b2.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            if score >= count_b1:
                score = score - count_b2
                count_b1 += 1000
            #вот тут нужно прописать как добавить логику каждую секунду + 1 очко

screen.fill("black")
draw_obj()
Texts()
pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Проблема, даже не затрагивает код, меня интересует сама логика как сделать так что бы каждую секунду прибовлять очки к счёту, я пробовал через цикл While но при этом всегда встречаю краш програмы из-за бесконечного цикла, я облазил все форумы и такое ощущение что никто таким не занимался XD

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае одним из возможных решений будет добавление определённого значения к сумме в цикле while (1/кол-во кадров в секунду), однако стоит учитывать, что для этого необходимо задать ограничение на раскадровку.
Ещё одним способом будет каждые n итераций цикла добавлять усреднённое значение.

Comment: я пробовал добавлять цикл While но приложение крашится потому что там бесконечность выходить разными способами пытался сделать замедление цикла но никак не выходит, какие ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

В *Pygame* существует событие таймера. 
Используйте `pygame.time.set_timer()` для повторного создания `USEREVENT`. 
Например так:

```
timer_interval = 1000                                      # 1 сек.
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event , timer_interval)
```

[**pygame.time.set_timer()**](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) - повторно создавать событие в очереди событий

Установите событие, которое будет появляться в очереди событий каждые
заданное количество миллисекунд.

---

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

counter = 0
text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 255, 255))

timer_interval = 1000
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1                                    # <---- 
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)                    # <---- старт

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == timer_event:                               # <---- 
            counter += 1                                              # <----
            text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 255, 255))
            if counter == 42:                                         # стоп 
                timer_interval = 0
                pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)                 # <---- стоп

    window.fill((205, 92, 92))
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center)      
    window.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @LwLast что не так?